# Swagger Codegen generates an api for each resource

Tags: php, swagger, openapi, swagger-codegen, swagger-editor

I created a swagger.json using the open-api-3 standart to be able to generate a client-sdk using the tool swagger-codegen.
My problem is that each API-endpoint ends up getting its own api-object instead of one api object for all endpoints of the api.

Expected:

```
$api->getArticles();
$api->getUsers();
```

Actual:

```
$articleApi->getArticles();
$userApi->getUsers();
```

[image]

**Question:**
How can I configure swagger codegen or my swagger.json to create only one api object for all entities/resources?

I used https://editor.swagger.io/ to generate the sdk in this example but I had the same result with the offline java version.

Here is my swagger.json : https://pastebin.com/kDZpSDtc

Answer (score 0):

Remove "tags" with its content.
I don't know what other code-generation settings there are in php, but in java pom.xml there is also a setting true
If you remove it or set to false, it generates one Api class.

**yaml:**

```
put:
  summary: Getting something from DB
  operationId: produced
  tags:           <--remove
    **- getting** <--remove
  requestBody:
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<configOptions>
            <useTags>true</useTags> <--remove or 'false'
            <library>spring-mvc</library>
            <dateLibrary>java8-localdatetime</dateLibrary>
            <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
            <hideGenerationTimestamp>true</hideGenerationTimestamp>
</configOptions>
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.